# Webpacker not interpolating the environment correctly to get to the right config file for the environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, capistrano, webpacker

We recently upgraded webpacker in our project. Now when I deploy with capistrano, I get a compilation error like:

```
webpack config /path/to/project/releases/20210617155029/config/webpack/.js not found, please run 'bundle exec rails webpacker:install' to install Webpacker with default configs or add the missing config file for your custom environment.
```

The obvious issue here is that webpacker is not looking for the correct config file, which should be config/webpack/staging.js in this case because I am deploying to the staging environment.

If I try to deploy again after such a failed attempt, it compiles just fine. It is as though whatever webpacker uses to determine the deployment environment is not set until a failed deploy happens. Does anyone know how webpacker determines the rails environment?